# Республиканское предприятие: со строчной или прописной?

Tags: орфография

> Республиканское унитарное предприятие «Днепр»

С какой буквы пишется слово "республиканское"? Есть ли какое-то правило?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В названиях предприятий, организаций с заглавной буквы пишется лишь первое слово и имена собственные, если они включены в это название. Так что в Вашем предложении слово "республиканское" нужно писать с большой буквы

Comment: С большой, если так действительно выглядит официальное название. Если же на самом деле оно называется, к примеру, "Всероссийское унитарное предприятие", но иногда его называют республиканским, то "республиканское" нужно писать со строчной.

Answer (score 0):

Писать надо так, как в уставе. Если приводимое название не является точным уставным название, то со строчной.